# How to get perf script to show string args to system calls as text, not pointer values?

Tags: linux, arm, embedded, perf

I am attempting to track deleted files with perf. I know eBPF / SystemTap is better suited here, but I am limited on the platform with tool choices (ARM).

This is how I am recording it

```
perf record -e 'syscalls:sys_enter_unlinkat'
```

For reporting

```
perf script -F +pid,+tid,-cpu
rm 15746/15746  7942.646974: syscalls:sys_enter_unlinkat: dfd: 0xffffff9c, pathname: 0x55a7960e6490, flag: 0x00000000
rm 15748/15748  7944.626120: syscalls:sys_enter_unlinkat: dfd: 0xffffff9c, pathname: 0x55dea122f490, flag: 0x00000000
rm 15750/15750  7947.111921: syscalls:sys_enter_unlinkat: dfd: 0xffffff9c, pathname: 0x55a515165490, flag: 0x00000000
```

How do I get string version of `pathname` as similar to that of strace output.
I also need uid of the process that deleted the file.

Comment: This is a question about a Linux utility not about code, programming or software development.  It is therefore not an SO question.

Comment: @Clifford: Seems possibly ok to me; `perf script` is basically a scripting language, I think.  (And also, although these factors *wouldn't* be sufficient on their own, generally only embedded developers are going to be using this tool this way; on a normal system you'd just use `strace`.  I'm not arguing that everything an embedded developer does is automatically an SO question, but since there is a valid reason to consider it a programming question, that's also more justification for letting it stay on SO instead of migrating to superuser where it would also be on topic.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : OK - objection withdrawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not be possible to obtain the string version of `pathname` using `perf` tools in this case.

When a userspace utility calls `perf_even_open` syscall with a request to monitor tracepoint events, such as the one you are trying to monitor with `syscalls:sys_enter_unlinkat`, a 'perf probe' function is attached to the tracepoint. You can see the probe function [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.27/source/include/trace/perf.h#L33).

The probe function allocates a [perf buffer](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.27/source/include/trace/perf.h#L58) and [validates](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.27/source/include/trace/perf.h#L68) the allocated buffer after which it invokes a [bpf](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.27/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L92) program.

This bpf program needs to know the 'format' of the static tracepoint event, since it needs to understand what is the structure of the binary trace output in the perf ring buffer.

The format of the event is defined in the `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_unlinkat/format` file, for your case.

If you look at this file, you will see that `perf script` reports the output as per the `print fmt` entry in the field.

```
name: sys_enter_unlinkat
ID: 722
format:
        field:unsigned short common_type;       offset:0;       size:2; signed:0;
        field:unsigned char common_flags;       offset:2;       size:1; signed:0;
        field:unsigned char common_preempt_count;       offset:3;       size:1; signed:0;
        field:int common_pid;   offset:4;       size:4; signed:1;

        field:int __syscall_nr; offset:8;       size:4; signed:1;
        field:int dfd;  offset:16;      size:8; signed:0;
        field:const char * pathname;    offset:24;      size:8; signed:0;
        field:int flag; offset:32;      size:8; signed:0;

print fmt: "dfd: 0x%08lx, pathname: 0x%08lx, flag: 0x%08lx", ((unsigned long)(REC->dfd)), ((unsigned long)(REC->pathname)), ((unsigned long)(REC->flag))
```

The `perf` userspace utility will always adhere to this format and will not deviate from it. You can see some details from [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/98b5c2c65c2951772a8fc661f50d675e450e8bce) commit.

Without a really extensive modification to the kernel tracepoint API, I do not see a way to achieve what you want using `perf`.

If all you are looking for is to track file deletion activity and you want to get additional details about it, I would suggest you try and take a look at [fanotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html).

Comment: Thanks for fanotify definitely worth looking at. However I switched to ply. It's a very minimal wrapper for eBPF. It's reportedly very buggy but worked fine for me in this scenario.